# How can I get UITextView to prevent page turning in parent UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

I want the user to be able to scroll the text, and not have the pageViewController receive any touch events if they happen within the textView.

If touch events happen outside the textView, I do want the page controller to respond.

How do i go about this?

Here is how it is set up in IB:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What happens when you add the textView as a subview?

Comment: If the textView is a subview this should not happen. You can read up on the UIResponder chain at this link (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html).

Comment: I added an image in my question showing how the UITextView was added in IB